# Looking for a unified framework for cloud backups

Tags: backup, cloud-storage

There are lots of solutions for e.g. backing up a database or a server. I don't want to manage physical servers, I want something that is basically stateless and can back up some set of data sources to an object store (S3, GCS, Azure.)

I have been thinking of writing a scheduled job that basically has some number of data sources and backs them up to the cloud. I need to be able to encrypt the backups with a key. In a perfect world some form of deduplication might be supported. The encryption and deduplication pieces are complicated enough that I'm thinking some sort of a framework (or service) would be nice so I don't have to roll my own and can reuse it. At a high level I'm imagining some sort of configuration that lets me define backups like:

```
DataSource mydatasource {
  authentication : <>,
  type: <>,
  encryption: <>,
  retention_policy: {
    days: 7
    weeks: 4
    months: 12
  }
}
```

`type` obviously needs to be pluggable and have support for different things. Types that I would want support for or would have to write plugins for are e.g.:

- Generic SQL

  - Generic Postgres

    - Amazon RDS Postgres
    - Redshift
    - Google Cloud SQL
- Generic Blob Store

  - Amazon S3
  - Google Cloud Storage
- Generic Object Store

  - DynamoDB
  - MongoDB
    etc.

The storage backend would probably look like Rclone, if not just being rclone. I'm willing to pay money for something that is seamless enough. Ideally there would be a CLI and a UI for invoking and restoring backups, and I could just run it on a cron and it would figure things out, taking new backups and cleaning up old ones.

The tagline for the piece of software I'm looking for would probably be "Like Apple TimeMachine, but for Google Cloud Platform or Amazon Web services."

Someone mentioned Barracuda, but AFAIK they only support O365, which is a very different problem space from what I'm looking to do.

Comment: This is well outside my field, but have you looked at Backblaze B2. [As a consumer, I use their regular backup structure, but they keep trying to sell me this one too… I wouldn't know where to start, tbh ;)

Comment: Backblaze B2 is just a competitor to Amazon S3 or Google Cloud Storage. What I want might support backing up to B2 but B2 is not the thing I want.